# Plotting sentences in Wordcloud in R

Tags: r, word-cloud, wordcloud2

I want to create a wordcloud where each line is displayed based on its count/frequency. The wordcloud should not be based on single words but on each sentence. The issue is that if I use wordcloud2, it does not display longer sentences and omits 2 of such sentences from the sample. How can I view all the sentences?
Below is a dummy dataset similar to original:

```
grp= c("Having awesome day, having good day, or having extremely bad day", "Good collection", "Won lottery or quiz",
       "credit card or prepaid card", "Transfer","Bitcoin, stock market, or bank deposit", "House loan or lease",
       "Study outside, local university, or own business", "Stay back")
freq= c(256,57,47,44,17,8,4,3,3)
data= data.frame(grp,freq)
```

Could someone please tell me if there is an alternative in the wordcloud to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot all the sentences you would need to reduce the `scale` value.

```
library(wordcloud)

wordcloud(data$grp, data$freq, scale=c(.5,.3), random.order=TRUE, 
          colors="black", vfont=c("sans serif","plain"))
```